# Objeto da InnerClass é criado em qual momento?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Tenho uma classe a qual contém uma InnerClass, gostaria de saber se no momento que eu dou `new ClassePrincipal()` a InnerClass também é criada?

Answer (score 3):

Uma InnerClass é criada quando se usa o operador `new` para se criar uma instância dela. Por exemplo:

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Comando: new outter");
        Outter out = new Outter();

        System.out.println("Comando: new inner");
        Outter.Inner in = out.new Inner();

        System.out.println("Comando: inner toString");
        System.out.println(in);     

        System.out.println("Comando: static inner toString");
        System.out.println(new Outter.StaticInner());
    }
}

class Outter {
    public Outter() {
        super();
        System.out.println("Outter criada");
    }
    public class Inner {
        public Inner() {
            super();
            System.out.println("Inner criada");
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "inner toString";
        }
    }
    public static class StaticInner {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "static inner toString";
        }
    }
}
```

Saída:

> Comando: new outter
>   Outter criada
>   Comando: new inner
>   Inner criada
>   Comando: inner toString
>   inner toString
>   Comando: static inner toString
>   static inner toString

Repare no código acima que o construtor das classes internas só foram chamados quando explicitamente criados com um `new`, tanto para a classe interna estática quanto a não-estática. Antes disso não havia por quê as classes internas terem sido instanciadas.

Answer (score 1):

Não. A inner class só é criada quando você fizer uma referência estática a ela ou instanciá-la.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
public class Classe {

    static {
        System.out.println("Carregou Classe");
    }

    public Classe() {
        System.out.println("Instanciou Classe");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Classe();
    }

    static class InnerClasse {

        static {
            System.out.println("Carregou InnerClasse"); // não será chamado
        }

        public InnerClasse() {
            System.out.println("Instanciou InnerClasse"); // não será chamado
        }
    }
}
```

O output deste programa é:

```
Carregou Classe
Instanciou Classe
```

Comment: No seu exemplo a sua `InnerClasse` não está dentro de nenhuma outra classe, você não confundiu alguma coisa ao criar seu exemplo?

Comment: @Math, obrigado, tinha me confundido. Já editei a resposta.

Comment: Acabou que minha resposta ficou bem parecida com a sua, não tava entendendo bem até parar e ler com atenção. Bom, aí vai meu +1